# SQL Server date format function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
```

This query return the date in the [DD-MM-YYYY]
 format as varchar. I need the same format in datetime datatype in sql server. Pls help me out

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)  AS DATETIME)`

Comment: @Verrigo; no he is not looking this.

Comment: i need to store the return value to the table column, which is datetime type

Comment: @Verrigo, it is returning in another format like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, a DATETIME datatype is stored as 2 4-byte integers so as such doesn't have a particular formatting like this.

If you want to return the date in a specific format, you need to CONVERT it to VARCHAR with the appropriate format identifier specified.

If you have a datetime in a VARCHAR and want to store that in a DATETIME field in SQL Server, then you should make sure you pass that value to SQL in a format that will always be safely interpreted. e.g. dd/mm/YYYY format is not safe as depending on settings, it could be treated as mm/dd/yyyy when it goes in. Safe formats are:

```
yyyyMMdd
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm
```

e.g.

```
INSERT MyTable (DateField) VALUES ('01/10/2010') -- dd/MM/yyyy not safe
INSERT MyTable (DateField) VALUES ('20101001') -- yyyyMMdd safe
```

**Update:**
When you SELECT a DATETIME field (GETDATE(), field, variable....) what you see in SSMS is a formatted value as this is what is useful to you, instead of it showing it's actual internal 8byte representation.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is,

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 105)
```

Just Changed `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`

Comment: that is not what he is looking for.

Comment: @Robinclave check this http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/ . It might help, but i think to format date is possible but getting it in `datetime` datatype is only possible by changing the sql server settings (i.e might be system settings)

Answer (score 0):

This will return a datetime

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Comment: here, the return type is varchar right? I need it in datetime datatype

Comment: @Robin Clave - no, GETDATE() returns DATETIME

Comment: Thats true. I said for SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)