# SQL SERVER 2008 :How to convert DATETIME to MM/yy format

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me how I can display the `MONTH` column in the following script to `MM/yy` format and sort the data by fiscal year order?

Currently the `MONTH` column format is: `2015-07-01 00:00:00.000`, but I want to display it as `07/15` and comes before `01/16`.

```
  SELECT 'New Clients' AS STATUS,
  dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,EFFECT_DT),0) as MONTH,
  COUNT(CLT_NBR) AS COUNT 
  FROM STATUS S
  WHERE EFFECT_DT BETWEEN '07/01/2015' AND '06/30/2016' 
  GROUP BY dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,EFFECT_DT),0)
```

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't _have_ a format - it only has a format when you _display_ it.  So you can either convert it to a string with a specific format or leave it as a DeteTime and let the _consumer_ decide the format.

Comment: You should format the data to display in the user-interface layer instead of in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server date format function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178452/sql-server-date-format-function)

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
  DECLARE @EFFECT_DT datetime = '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'
  SELECT 'New Clients' AS STATUS,
  FORMAT(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@EFFECT_DT),0),'MM/yy') as MONTH
```

Results

```
        STATUS       MONTH 
    New Clients  |   07/15
```

Comment: Format function has been added to MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: This is good for displaying, but it removes the `DATETIME` datatype of the field.
`SELECT ISDATE(FORMAT(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,'2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'),0),'MM/yy')) as IS_DATE`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that your issue is 2-fold: [(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx). Formatting the date, and [(2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx). ordering using specific portions within a date.

Note:
As we know, time moves in a linear fashion. Thus ordering by fiscal year / normal year should be no different (unless I'm misunderstanding a requirement of yours)

**Solution:**

1. To format the Date for *"display"* purposes you can make use of [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx), and specify a format such as `MM/yy`. (I use the term display loosely, but right tool for the right job and what not)
2. Order the output set by the individual date part components. Do so by using the aplty named [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

**Sample:**

```
-- build some sample data
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE() 

-- just a quick hack. use whatever data source you'd like
SELECT [Id], [SomeDate]
INTO   [#SampleData]
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS [Id], DATEADD(month, -2, @date) AS [SomeDate] 
        UNION 
        SELECT 2, DATEADD(month, 1, @date) 
        UNION 
        SELECT 3, DATEADD(year, 1, @date) 
        UNION 
        SELECT 4, @date 
        UNION 
        SELECT 5, DATEADD(year, -5, @date) 
        UNION 
        SELECT 6, DATEADD(year, 2, @date)) AS [SampleData] 

-- select in whatever format then order by year & month
SELECT [Id], 
       FORMAT([SomeDate], 'MM/yy') [ShortDate], 
       FORMAT([SomeDate], 'MMM yy') [SortDateInText] 
FROM   [#SampleData]
ORDER  BY DATEPART(year, [SomeDate]) DESC, --or ascending
          DATEPART(month, [SomeDate])
```

Answer (score 0):

Building of @dejan87's answer, if you don;t have FORMAT available to you on an older version of SQL server, you can work it with the DATEPART function...

```
  DECLARE @EFFECT_DT datetime 
  set @EFFECT_DT= '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'

  SELECT 'New Clients' AS STATUS,
  right('00' + cast(DatePart(month, @EFFECT_DT) as varchar(2)), 2) +  '/' + 
  right(cast(DatePart(year, @EFFECT_DT) as varchar(4)), 2) as [MONTH]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Just to ask strictly to question from title:

> how-to-convert-datetime-to-MM/dd-format

**SQL2012+**

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd')
```

**SQL2000+**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 101)
```

2) Assuming that I would have to filter rows for one year then I would use following solution:

```
SELECT  *
FROM ...
WHERE EFFECT_DT >= '20150701' 
AND EFFECT_DT < '20160701' -- or EFFECT_DT <= '20160630 23:59:59.997'
```

Note #1: When data type is `DATETIME`, above predicates will filter all rows between `2015-07-01 00:00:00.000` and `2016-06-30 23:59:59.997`.

Note #2: `.997` is maximum precision for a `DATETIME` column.

Note #3: Please notice string formats used for those DT values: `yyyymmdd` and `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.mmm`. Both formats are independent from `DATEFORMAT` setting.