# SQL Server : convert date to YYYMMDD?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a date in one of the column in SQL Server, the sample dates are:

```
10/02/2012
23/11/2012
13/01/2012
10/02/2012
10/02/2012
```

I have tried the approach to convert the dates to `YYYYMMDD`

```
DECLARE @v DATE= '1/11/2012'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @v, 112)
```

I have another column in a same table in which i want to update the date in `YYYYMMDD` format ,the problem here is that the date are not proper 
and throws an error

```
DECLARE @v DATE= '23/11/2012'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @v, 112)
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any help is appreciated in this, The date will come in any order either dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, it should be able to convert it properly

Comment: If you are getting strings and it is inconsistent about dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy you are fighting a losing battle. How do you know which one is which? What about 12/10/2016? Which "format" is that and how would you know? This is why you should NEVER store dates as varchar. There is a datatype that is far better for this type of data. It is known as date or datetime.

Comment: A) What column type are you storing your dates as? B) If you don't know the format of the date to start with, how will you ever be able to reliably format output? E.g. 10/04/2016 = October or April?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server date format function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178452/sql-server-date-format-function)

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the following format to one data type to another.(dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd)

`CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)`

As well as update like following

```
UPDATE table_name SET
    destination_column_name=orig_column_name
WHERE condition_if_necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert date in SQL server you want to follow certain formats. You can follow either `yyyy-MM-dd` or `MM-dd-yyyy`

for your question if you follow `MM-dd-yyyy` this format and if you using SQL server 2012 or newer you can use this and you can get the result

```
DECLARE @v DATE = '11/23/2012';

SELECT FORMAT ( @v, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en-US' )
```

Refer these links [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) , [SQL Server date format function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178452/sql-server-date-format-function)