# Set the default value of a datetime column to be in 24h format in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I want to set the default value of my "Date" column (using getdate() by exemple) to be stored in 24h and not in 12h format.

In my SQL Server database I set the default value to be : getdate(). In the database it displays like I want it in 24h format : `22/06/2016 10:46:00`

But when I get this value in my php website I get the following value : `Jun 22 2016 10:46:00:000AM`

I know that there are ways to convert for what I want like : `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)`

But I can't set this query to be the default value of my "Date" column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server date format function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178452/sql-server-date-format-function)

Comment: Datetime has *NO FORMAT*. It's a binary value. What you see is the value formatted into a string using either the collation of the database or the culture of your code. If you want to change how the date is rendered as a string somewhere, change the code that does the rendering

Comment: What is the type of the column? Is it one of the date types or varchar? If it's a date type you shouldn't care how it appears in SSMS. If it's varchar, it's the wrong type and you will run into localization errors at some point, eg a web server set to a US locale will choke if it reads `22/06/2016`

Comment: The proper place to change how the date is displayed in your web site is the web site itself. You can easily specify the format used to render a bound value in almost all frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much everyone ! So to sum up I learned from you that "Datetime" is a binary value so it has no format.

So if it displays good in the SQL Server and not in my PHP website it is because php interpret the binary value differently.

To finally make it displays the way I want in PHP I format it in PHP using (note : $row["Date"] is the cell where I get the "Date" binary value from the SQL Server) :

```
$datee = new DateTime($row["Date"]);
$dateee = $datee->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

And the output is now :

```
2016/06/22 10:46:00
```