# C# SSIS Script Component Format Input Date Row to "MMddyyyy"

Tags: c#, ssis

I am currently working on a Transformation component script. I want to format the input date columns to "MMddYYYY".

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    /*
     * Add your code here
     */

    Row.SampleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Row.SampleDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    Row.TestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Row.TestDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    Row.ComponentsTestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Row.ComponentsTestDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
}
```

I am still getting a timestamp value once the scripts executes:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot looks like the data viewer. If the pipeline's column is set to data time (i.e., DB_TIMESTAMP) then the date time will should no matter what. You should be able to output that value to a DATE column on SQL Server, which will have the time removed if it is all zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings have formats.   [DateTimes do not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178599/1507566).

If you want to see your output in a specific format, you need your output column to be a string datatype.